# Regular expression that contains some logic

Tags: php, regex

I am looking a regular expression that contains two logic:
1. Does not contain any white space
2. Must contain (/ or . or both) . Number of (/ or .) may be one or multiple.

```
$text = "Hi jaghdja ahja.ja//hda manmna.bnm bana na/bbnavn.com"; //for an example
//expecting output an array("ahja.ja//hda","manmna.bnm","na/bbnavn.com");
```

What I am using

```
preg_match_all("#([^\s]|\.|\/)*#",$a,$arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Like [`'~\S*[/.]\S*~'`](https://regex101.com/r/hBEMsX/1)?

Comment: / or . may be multiple and its position is not fixed. may be .aaa/hhjh

Comment: Note you can also achieve what you want [without regex](https://ideone.com/Etgjgw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
[^/.\s]*[./]\S*
```

**Code:**

```
preg_match_all('~[^/.\s]*[./]\S*~', $a, $arr);
print_r($arr);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eHeVnb/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `[^/.\s]*`: Match a character that is not a `/` and not a `.` and not a white-space
- `[./]`: Match a dot or forward slash
- `\S*`: Match 0 or more non-white-space character

Comment: Thank you. Let me have a try.